# Сумма цифр натурального числа

Tags: java

Имеется натуральное число `n`. Например, оно вводится с клавиатуры вот так:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = scanner.nextInt();
```

Как я могу получить сумму цифр этого числа?

```
int sumDigits = ???
System.out.println(sumDigits);
```

Comment: Ну смотри ты же в цикле прибавляешь последнюю цифру, но с самим то числом ничего не происходит. То есть ты добавляешь одну и ту же цифру.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

вроде как, должно быть так:

```
while(n != 0){
       //Суммирование цифр числа
        sum += (n % 10);
        n/=10;
}
System.out.println(sum + " ");
```

Comment: Опередили =)

Answer (score 5):

через for тоже можно, они взаимозаменяемы с while:

```
for(n = sr.nextInt(); n != 0; n /= 10)
{ 
    sum += (n % 10); 
} 
System.out.println(sum + " ");
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ @Valeriy Karchov

Comment: Подскажите как еще можно подсчитать количество цифр в числе?

Comment: Крутой вариант! Добавлю тогда еще)

    while((n/=10) != 0)
        sum = sum + (n % 10);
    System.out.println(sum + " ");

Comment: тогда

     do
         sum = sum + (n % 10);
     while((n/=10) != 0);   

иначе теряется самая правая цифра

Comment: Да точно!

Answer (score 2):

У вас цикл не выполняется ни разу, т.к. `n` изначально не равно 0.
Поставьте знак `!=` и все должно заработать. И в цикле добавить строчку `n /= 10`.

Answer (score 2):

нельзя задачу решать "в лоб". считать число а потом выполнять кучу операций деления это не лучший вариант, когда у вас есть возможность обработать каждый символ отдельно

```
  final Scanner s = new Scanner ( System.in );
  final String line = s.nextLine ().trim ();
  final char [] array = line.toCharArray ();

  int sum = 0;
  for ( final char c : array )
  {
     if ( !Character.isDigit ( c ) )
     {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ();
     }

     sum = sum + Character.getNumericValue ( c );
  }

  System.out.println ( "sum = " + sum );
```

Comment: Можете пояснить почему? Интересуюсь, потому что часто слышу споры о том, что в таких задачах лучше использовать строки, но без какой-либо аргументации, хотелось бы знать Ваше мнение

Comment: Что-то я очень сильно сомневаюсь, что ваш вариант будет работать быстрее, чем простое целочисленное деление. А по читабельности вариант с делением (для меня, по крайней мере) отчетливо предпочтительней.

Comment: Это работает раз в десять дольше.

Answer (score 2):

Для читаемости или 
чтобы поддерживать числа со многими цифрами, можно [Java Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) использовать. Суммируем значения символов во вводе как десятичных цифр:

```
int sum = input.chars().map(c -> Character.digit(c, 10)).sum();
```

где `input` это [строка из ввода](https://ideone.com/bLI4cz):

```
String input = scanner.next();
```

или ввод с консоли:

```
String input = System.console().readLine();
```

Если ввод дан как `int`, то [простейший цикл работает](https://ideone.com/iaORns):

```
for ( ; n > 0; n /= 10)
    sum += n % 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int digitSum(int number) {
    return (number == 0)
        ? 0
        : (number % 10) + digitSum(number / 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    sum(n, sum);
}
public static void sum(int n, int sum){
    if(n!=0){
       sum+=n%10;
       sum(n/10, sum);
    }
    else System.out.println(sum);
}
```

}

Comment: Используя рекурсию

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int s = 0;
        for(int n = Math.abs((new Scanner(System.in)).nextInt()); n > 0; s += n % 10, n /= 10);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println((num % 10) + (num / 10) % 10 + (num / 100));
    }
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]